# MySQL Query to calculate unique id, count number of records and group by (3 tables)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables engagements, patient_services and patients.
This Query

```
SELECT 
    ps_user_loc AS loc, COUNT(ps_id) AS ser, Count(Distinct  ps_ur) AS patient
FROM patient_services 
GROUP BY loc 

UNION ALL 

SELECT 
    eng_user_loc AS loc, COUNT(eng_id) AS ser, Count(Distinct  eng_ur) AS patient 
FROM engagements 
WHERE LENGTH( eng_ur )>0 
GROUP BY loc
```

returns

```
loc           ser   patient 
CABOOLTURE    354       255
KILCOY         15        12 
RBWH         1840       476 
RBWH           34        27 
REDCLIFFE       3         3 
TPCH           11         9
```

So loc has doubles and I can calculate ser in php loop
But Patients count not unique because the same id in engagements and patient_services tables.

How to make select grouped by Location with number of Services and unique Patients in two tables(not in each like it now)?

Thank you.

Comment: You are welcomed. But what is the question?

Comment: @Shadow 
How to make select grouped by Location with number of Services and unique Patients in two tables(not in each like it now)?

Comment: An `ur` (`ps_ur`, `eng_ur`) is a patient ID? And the word `ser` means something like "how many records"? And you want one result row per loc with the `ser` sum and the distinct patient count, because you don't care whether you find a record in `patient_services` or `engagements`?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner for two tables `patient_services` and `engagements` the `ps_ur`, `eng_ur` it's the `patient_ur` from the table `patient`. For `ser` I don't care and need only number of records. But need to count unique `ur`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is a full outer join. That would be two steps: 1. get loc/patient pairs from the tables and join, 2. aggregate by loc. In standard SQL:

```
select 
  loc, 
  sum(coalesce(ps.cnt, 0) + coalesce(e.cnt, 0)), 
  count(distinct patient)
from
(
  select
    ps_user_loc as loc, 
    ps_ur as patient,
    count(*) as cnt
  from patient_services
  group by ps_user_loc, ps_ur
) ps
full outer join
(
  select
    eng_user_loc as loc, 
    eng_ur as patient
    count(*) as cnt,
  from engagements
  where length(eng_ur) > 0
  group by eng_user_loc, eng_ur
) e using (loc, patient)
group by loc;
```

Unfortunately MySQL doesn't support full outer joins (and the using clause neither). One way is to get all locs/patients first and then left join:

```
select
  l.loc, 
  sum(coalesce(ps.cnt, 0) + coalesce(e.cnt, 0)), 
  count(distinct l.patient)
from
(
  select ps_user_loc as loc, ps_ur as patient from patient_services
  union
  select eng_user_loc as loc, eng_ur as patient from engagements
) l
left outer join
(
  select
    ps_user_loc as loc, 
    ps_ur as patient,
    count(*) as cnt
  from patient_services
  group by ps_user_loc, ps_ur
) ps on ps.loc = l.loc and ps.patient = l.patient
left outer join
(
  select
    eng_user_loc as loc, 
    eng_ur as patient,
    count(*) as cnt
  from engagements
  where length(eng_ur) > 0
  group by eng_user_loc, eng_ur
) e on e.loc = l.loc and e.patient = l.patient
group by l.loc;
```

Comment: 'select
  l.loc, 
  sum(coalesce(ps.cnt, 0) + coalesce(e.cnt, 0)) AS ser, 
  count(distinct l.patient) AS patient 
from
(
  select ps_user_loc as loc, ps_ur as patient from patient_services 
  union
  select eng_user_loc as loc, eng_ur as patient  from engagements where length(eng_ur) > 0
) l
left outer join
(

  ...'